# Simple case of stopImmediatePropagation() is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation

Here is a small JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lotchi/965eLa7g/`stopImmediatePropagation() Chrome VS IE`
I'm using a library called Handsontable to manage a table as an excelsheet.

In my example, I just want to avoid my user to use Delete and Backspace key of the keyboard in a row for which one of the column has a specific value.

The example is working fine in Chrome but not in IE. 
I already find some comment about this in the forum but no one is related to the keybord key, always about clicking.

Can you please advise?

Comment: the user can still mark the cell and cut the text out. whats your goal?

Comment: how about making the table read only? http://jsfiddle.net/88p6sndv/1/

Comment: Actually my goal is to check the value on one column which is representing a status. And if this status is "Approved" I want to avoid Delete and BackSpace button on the whole row. (In my example  the condition could be if column with the year is less than 2018)

Comment: Here is ,my updated Jiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lotchi/965eLa7g/

Comment: I found a problem. try replacing: `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` with `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: nope... http://jsfiddle.net/Lotchi/L3yp5xjz/  nothing change in IE. Still OK in Chrome.

Comment: you should figure out where the problem is. another guess would be `e.key` is not the same in IE then in Chrome so your `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` gets never called.

Comment: Indeed :-) Sorry about that... This is my first experience in Javascript and web dev on Fiori .  Thanks a lot for your help @RolandStarke

Answer (score 0):

The issue was somewhere else in the code. Indeed a condition was set on the event key value which is not the same in each browser. ("DELETE" vs "DEL)

See here a example which is working for delete button in Chrome and IE
http://jsfiddle.net/on9358kw/`solution`